# Implementation of Hierarchical Sampling for Active Learning

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, hierarchical-clustering

I am working on a personal machine learning project where I am attempting to classify data into binary classes when the classes are extremely imbalanced. I am initially trying to implement the approach proposed in [`Hierarchical Sampling for Active Learning` by `S Dasgupta`](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~djhsu/papers/hier.pdf) which exploits the cluster structure of the dataset to aide the active learner.

However, I am struggling to implement the algorithm proposed in the article. I have written this so far, however am unsure how to continue:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import linkage, dendrogram
data_dist = pdist(X) # computing the distance
data_link = linkage(data_dist) # computing the linkage
```

The data is stored in `X` and the correct clasification in `y`. Sample dataset:

```
X = np.array([[0.3,0.7],[0.5,0.5] ,[0.2,0.8], [0.1,0.9]])
y = np.array([[0], [1], [0], [1]])
```

(Note the actual dataset is approximately 500 times larger)

Comment: hey @JDOE were you able to implement this? I'm stuck on the same issue right now...

Comment: @snazziii Its now included in [libact](https://libact.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). See [this](https://github.com/ntucllab/libact/blob/master/libact/query_strategies/multiclass/hierarchical_sampling.py).

Answer (score 0):

Hierarchical Sampling for Active Learning as proposed by S Dasgupta is now implemented in [libact](https://libact.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), a Python active learning libary. For the source code, see this [link](https://github.com/ntucllab/libact/blob/master/libact/query_strategies/multiclass/hierarchical_sampling.py).

Example (from doccumentation):

```
   from libact.query_strategies import UncertaintySampling
   from libact.query_strategies.multiclass import HierarchicalSampling
   sub_qs = UncertaintySampling(
       dataset, method='sm', model=SVM(decision_function_shape='ovr'))
   qs = HierarchicalSampling(
            dataset, # Dataset object
            dataset.get_num_of_labels(),
            active_selecting=True,
            subsample_qs=sub_qs
        )
```